# clickable text in header.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I have some text in the **header.php** in WordPress which I want to be clickable, but it isn't ?

```
<div id="languages">ES | 
    <a href="../index_g.html">DE</a> |
    <a href="../index.html">ENG</a>
</div>
```

should these be written in PHP ? if so could you help please.

I tried

```
<div id="languages">ES | 
<?php echo( '<a href="../index_g.html">DE</a>' ); ?>
<?php echo( '<a href="../index_g.html">DE</a>' ); ?>
</div>
```

but that didn't work either. the text is still not clickable.

Comment: you mean the links arent working? or are you expecting some other behaviour?

Comment: Perhaps there is some other element over it through css, that prevents your from clicking? Try to inspect in browser, perhaps a z-index gone wrong.

Comment: may be there is a preventDefault() function in scripts

Comment: If you provide a link, we could troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #header div is sitting on top of your #languages div, which makes the links hidden.

To fix this, add the following styles to your #languages div.

```
#languages{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

z-index only works if an element has a defined position style, such as relative or absolute.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please be sure to accept it as the answer to the left of my answer. This helps others with similar problems.